# How to get a pop-up If we have any truncate or delete statement - when we are running script in toad or SQL developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

Is there any way can i get a pop-up in display , whenever any one runs a script ( script consists of multiple inserts , updates , delete statements )

Example for multiple statements:

```
Update table set A=A where EmpId= 1;
Delete from Table where Emp_ID =2;
```

When i run complete this complete commands in script , a popup should be triggered saying "I am trying delete operation & its a production database".

Is there any way i can get popup while i am running sql script ( in a script if any statement with truncate or delete ) can i get a popup in toad and Sql Developer.... ?

Please help me with suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the ACCEPT command ([Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve005.htm#SQPUG026))

[image]

```
set pause on -- this will wait for user input between pages/queries
set pagesize 200
SELECT employees.first_name,
       employees.last_name,
       employees.salary,
       departments.department_name
  FROM employees
 INNER JOIN departments ON employees.department_id = departments.department_id
 ORDER BY salary desc, last_name asc;

ACCEPT upd CHAR PROMPT 'Cut Salary 10 percent? (y/n):  '  -- add this before bad stuff

update employees set salary = salary * 0.9;
```

I think your real solution is to never manually run a script in production. You should never even be connected to production in most cases. And when you do need to make a change in production, issue a change order. That would include your script, which would get reviewed by a DBA. It would then get scheduled, and ran through a pre-approved process. And ALL of this would be audited.

This may sound 'crazy', but most DBAs upon reading your question would be very worried for the data in your database.

TL;DR short answer - your tools can't save you. They can only help. For example SQLDev allows you to add a color code to your connections to give you a visual reminder of where you are.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually sometime for initial loads we need to run scripts manually. Just to over come the issue if i have any drop statement by mistake then to be safe we are trying for solution.

Comment: @ Without Accept command , will there be any way we can right trigger so that if soemone trying to run drop or truncate just trigger warning or popu

Comment: if you take the time to write the update or truncate or drop...take the time to write the Accept - it's just one more safeguard. yes, you can write triggers, but every time you add a trigger, ask yourself, is this really necessary? they're often used as band-aids for bad design

Comment: @ Yes may be its a bad design. But May be some new guys may not include ACCEPT command  in their script. Just to be more safe if possible with trigger so that if someone suddenly run the script which has "drop" or "truncate" they should get a popup saying "trying to run drop"..  Is that possible ?

Comment: @avinash you asked how to get a popup in these tools, i've shown you. may be some new guys shouldn't be in production running scripts?

Comment: @smith -- Can you help me with some trigger code please ? so that i f i run the script automatically i should get popup ..Please or do i need to open a new question. ?

Comment: 2smith -- Do i need to open a new question ?

Comment: no trigger will cause a popup to show on your screen

Comment: Hi Smith. Need one suggestion. can i ask ?